# Call certain words in a string with and without capitals

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a keyword search thing in javascript. So javascript counts for example the word "cheese" but only without the capitals. So if for example the string is "Cheese cheese CHEESE" it only counts 1. The keyword is achieved from a $_POST['keyword']; with php

how can i do this with javascript...

```
var textFocus = $('#content').text();

var count = (textFocus.match(/<?php echo $_POST['keyword']; ?>/g) || []).length;
```

many thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

if you use `/ig` instad of `/g` in your `.match()`, it becomes case-insensitive

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `.toLowerCase()` to both `textFocus` and the keyword.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text="Cheese cheese CHEESE",
regex= new RegExp('cheese', 'gi');
console.log(text.match(regex).length);
```